# how to add date components to NSDate having time format

Tags: iphone

please see the following code

```
        NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
        NSDate *dat=pickerView.date;
        NSString *timerString=[outputFormatter stringFromDate:dat];

        [startTimer setTitle:timerString forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        timeString=timerString;
        [self updatePrayerTimigs];
        //dat=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:20];
        UILocalNotification *local=[[[UILocalNotification alloc]init] autorelease];
        UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
        if(local){
            local.fireDate=dat;
            local.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            //local.repeatInterval=0;
            local.alertBody=@"Hello";
            local.repeatInterval=NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
            [app scheduleLocalNotification:local];
            [app presentLocalNotificationNow:local];
        }// end of the if
```

I am selecting only time (Hour , minute) from UIDatePicker so i can fire notifications, so I decided to add current date to above NSDate with selected from UIDatePicker , please help how can I do that

Comment: Please be more elaborate about your question. Do you want to add date in the date picker?

Comment: i want to set local notification for the time selected from UIDatePicker(it contain only time) ,but unfortunately I can not set Local notification with only time ? I need to add date with that time

Answer (score 0):

Try this to format the date

```
 NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```